# Macbook Pro Retina with Chrome + background-attachment: fixed bug

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, retina-display

I know that this issue has been discussed before here but I tried every method and none of them worked. I'm trying to make a parallax effect with `background-attachment: fixed`. On every browser, on every OS is working perfectly **except** Chrome on Macbook Pro with Retina screen. [Here is the website](http://kuki.im/apc)

The webpage isn't renders properly. The elements which have `background-attachment: fixed` are flickering or don't load at all. If you have Retina you can understand what i'm saying. Just open it in Chrome. For those who don't have retina just [look at my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpkve.jpg). I'm desperate right now. I'm thinking of killing the functionality of this rule by targeting chrome on hDPI devices. Can i achieve this using jQuery maybe?

[many sources of this specific issue](http://goo.gl/mplgir)

Comment: It looks like you found a fix for this (at least it looks fine in Chrome on my retina display). Could you share what you did to get it to work?

Comment: It wasn't a fix. It was a conflict with overflow property from its parent. Somehow those two break stuff only on Retina. So I changed a lot of the code

Comment: @hambos22 I'm running into the same issue. Since the website you linked seems to be down, do you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: Never mind, removing `position: relative;` and setting html and body to both have `height: 100%;` solved my problem.