# background-attachment: fixed not scrolling on osx Chrome, only on Macbook screen

Tags: html, css, macos

This could be a repeat of [Macbook Pro Retina with Chrome + background-attachment: fixed bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074169/macbook-pro-retina-with-chrome-background-attachment-fixed-bug), but my issue is as follows:

I have a scroll container inside the body tag that scrolls the page, so something like:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <div style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: scroll;">
     <div style="height: 3000px"/>
     <div class="the-special-div-with-the-background"/>
     <div style="height: 3000px"/>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

With css something like:

```
.the-special-div-with-the-background {
    background: url('/img/the-image.png') no-repeat fixed 50% 50%;
}
```

I have a two monitor set up (let's call them monitors A and B), and I use my Macbook Pro Retina as a third monitor.  If I run this code in Chrome on monitor A or B, everything works as expected.  However if I drag the window over to my Macbook Pro Retina display (without refreshing the page), the code does not work as expected, specifically the image stops scrolling with the rest of the page (almost like the image has been positioned statically).  Everything works fine in Safari on all screens.

Note that if I remove the scroll container, everything works fine, i.e.

```
<html>
 <body>    
     <div style="height: 3000px"/>
     <div class="the-special-div-with-the-background"/>
     <div style="height: 3000px"/>
 </body>
</html>
```